# Fixed footer & relative DIV

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, html

I am soo confused right now. Coding really isn't my thing, so I believe that I messed up majorly somewhere which creates this problem:

I'm trying to make a sticky footer. The footer does stick--but only if I make my main content DIV (the white centered box) relative. I need the height of that DIV to stretch with the content (which will contain a PHP script that'll pull from my Wordpress blog--so naturally, I need it to adjust as necessary). If the DIV stretches longer than 500px, there's a weird two-scrollbars things going on, & I hate that. I like the relative DIV, but I would love to rid of all the extra scroll space, as well as making sure it stetches/regresses with content & the footer stays where it is.

I hope that's not too confusing. I'd just like someone to look over my source code & see where I'm going wrong. Thank you for any help.

http://www.missa.me/practice3.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nice website :)

You need to make the footer fixed,

use this CSS

```
#footer {
position: fixed;
height: 80px;
clear: both;
background-color: #fff;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

and take `overflow: auto;` off of `#main`

what this does is tell the footer to stay 'fixed' to the bottom of your viewport, so it will always stick to the bottom of your screen.. and taking `overflow:auto;` off will give your `#main` the natural ability to expand it's height depending on the content inside it.

Comment: :D I'm glad you like it! Oh my gosssssh. Thank you so much! Such a simple fix, iloveyou. o_o